Firebase Quotas FCM - "Send requests per minute"
If I add 20 devices into a FCM device group and then send a notification for the created device group (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#curl-command).
How does this count towards the "Send requests per minute" quota for FCM.
Will it count for 20 or just as a single request?


Please edit the question to be more clear which FCM limit you're talking about.  It would help to provide a link, and quote the relevant text from that page.

I appended a screenshot. The official name, as already mentioned, is "Send requests per minute"

firebaser here
I asked around, and as far as I can tell FCM currently counts the number of calls to the HTTP API, so sending to a device group would count as one towards your quota.

Thanks! Is your answer based on the paragraph:
When sending messages against the FCM HTTP v1 API, each request consumes an allotted Quota Token in a given time window. This window, called a "Token Bucket", refills to full at the end of the time window. For example: the HTTP v1 API allots 600K Quota Tokens for each 1-minute Token Bucket, which refills to full at the end of each 1-minute window.

My answer is based on asking the engineering team.  ;-) I clarified that in my answer.

Ok. In our account we were able to confirm that https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices is a single http request containing up to 500 tokens but still counts as 500 tokens towards the quota.
So why is it treated differently here?

The Admin SDK under the hood actually calls the FCM REST API for each individual token, so that indeed counts as separate calls for the quota. That this is unrelated to the device group question you posted though.

Ok. Thanks for clarification. I marked the question as resolved.
